# Допустимо ли использование MonoBehavior объектов на составных объектах при использовании ecs?

Tags: unity3d, ecs

Пытаюсь освоить leoecs. У него в примерах он компоненты заполняет через FindObject*.

Можно ли на компоненты составные объекты сцены навесить скрипт без Update и тп с параметрами [SerializedField] и уже с него брать параметры для компонентов ecs?

Comment: Выбросьте leoecs и используйте ECS из [DOTS](https://unity.com/dots).

Answer (score 0):

1. leoe**sc**? Может LeoE**CS**? (фреймвор о котором знают "полтора" человека)
2. `компоненты заполняет` компонент это MonoBehaviour скрипт. Его заполняют строками кода в виде переменных, методов и функций. Если только вы не имеете в виду DataWrapper, но тогда нужно уточнять.
3. `на компоненты составные объекты сцены навесить` так на компоненты или на составные объекты? существительное-существительное-глагол это не человеческий язык.
4. `без Update` можно без Awake, без Start, без Update  или FixedUpdate, без OnDestroy, без OnCollide, да без чего хочешь.
5. `параметрами`? у нас в ростове их кличут `переменными` и порой их делают `public`. На `SerializedField` забей, не заморачивайся.
6. `компонентов esc` это что за покемон? Опять-же Надеюсь не `ecs`... иначе нафига вам не владея ни матчастью ни русским языком лезть в многопоточные вычисления.

Comment: Все по делу, кроме 6 пункта, чем вам не понравились "компоненты ecs"?

Comment: Да уж лучше "esc" (не важно что это) чем "ecs") в теме многопоточных вычислений и разбития на jobs начинающему делать нечего. Разве не так?

Comment: Особенно если человек делает hyper casual свистелку-перделку на мобилку, что наверняка так с вероятностью в 99%...

Comment: А вы же знаете, что ECS не обязательно запускать на многопоточке?

Comment: Да, но смысл? Какова практическая цель в его случае... For The Science?

Comment: Ну вообще ECS - это просто "дружелюбная к железу" архитектура, на одном ядре она тоже будет шустро работать.

Comment: Да, и насколько читал архитектура приятная и с точки зрения манеры дробления кода, но всё-же не о таком нужно думать начинающему, который двух классов свизать не может.

Comment: Так я и не спорил с этим, я просто сказал, что не согласен с 6 пунктом :)

Comment: ECS - это совсем не про многопоточность, если что. Основная фишка - оптимальное использование L-кешей и раскладка данных по ним. Удобное распараллеливание - это лишь следствие, а не основная цель.